# Theme localization in WPML - .mo file error

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery, plugin-wpml, translation

We are creating a multi-lingual multi-site (on sub-domains/domain mapping) on Wordpress.

We recently bought WPML Wordpress plugin and installed it on the basic language (English) version. Now we are trying to work on Theme Localization.
Here we are following the steps as in [this guide](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/theme-localization/). Here we are being instructed to install a `.mo` file in Language locale settings. We are getting an error *File not found* (under MO file in `wp-content/Languages`).

This `.mo` file was downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/nextgen-gallery/downloads/detail?name=nggallery-zh_CN.mo.

Can anyone help? Is this `.mo` file the correct version? Is there any other source to get the correct .mo file? Are we using the right approach for theme localization?

Answer (score 2):

A `.mo` file is the machine readable Version of a `.po` file, which in turn holds the translation of a `.pot` file.
Hence, the latter is what you want to have in the first place.
And if it is your theme you want to localize, you certainly do not need a random plugin's simplified Chinese `.mo` file...

Using either, [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/), any other [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) application or the [Codestyling Localization Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/), you analyze your theme's PHP, a `.pot` file is created automatically and it is *then* that you can start creating translation files, one `.po` and `.mo` per language.

Also, add a `/languages/` folder to your theme (or plugin), rather than attempting to use `wp-content/languages`.

You might benefit from carefully reading the [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) codex article.